# Is there a 'minimum requirement' for users to know, to use SO?

Tags: discussion

Given that asking questions itself requires one to type it out in a WYSIWYG editor using html, one could say only those who know html should ask questions on SO - which seems pretty restrictive.

For example - 'how to install something - in the context of programming' questions or 'how to learn programming' questions ?

PS: This is related to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391955/review-triage-failed-for-24792516-what-is-wrong-with-the-question) question on meta that I just asked.

Comment: Yes it is. I mean should we also write the question for the asker? That also requires some thought.

Comment: I've very rarely written HTML directly into my posts, and when I have, I could have achieved a passable result without it. As for your examples, both software installation and requests for tutorials are off topic for Stack Overflow. I think your premise is a bit flawed, but perhaps [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) will answer some part of your question.

Comment: What does it actually mean to know about HTML? Is the ability to use the editor sufficient knowledge in that regard?

Comment: *"using html"* The text editors don't mainly use [HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) (Hypertext Markup Language), they use [MarkDown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown). Yes, [some HTML tags are accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1777/397219) as well, but most of the formatitng you see is created by users using MD, not HTML. Especially in the comments, where **only** Markdown can be used.

Comment: “How to learn programming” is unequivocally off-topic on SO, as has been discussed 14 trillion times. The question you failed the audit for is unwelcome because we expect users to make a sincere and focused effort to solve problems for themselves before asking experts to donate their time l. That includes reading error messages, creating and following a chain of logic, and only asking others as a last resort. I often make an analogy to the guild system: SO is` matters teaching journeymen. Apprentices aren’t members yet and need years of practice to become journeymen. Tutoring doesn’t scale.

Comment: At a minimum, you need to ask an appropriate question, and what is or isn't an appropriate question is reasonably explained in the SO help section. I'm not sure where you're getting the idea that knowledge of HTML is required.

Comment: @DanBron For someone who's heard of SO as a site for programmers (which to me it is), saying its only for experienced programmers is something that would cause them to turn away from the site. At what point should one consider themselves to be `journeymen`? If at all a post is not upto expectations, rather than delete it, the system could flag it as something that is retained but flag it as something that is discouraged with an explanation on what is expected.

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk - I guess I missed the obvious while posting it. However the intuition came from looking at the edits on the review queue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Given that asking questions itself requires one to type it out in a WYSIWYG editor using html [...]

The editor for both questions and answers does not *require* you to use HTML. Users may use a kind of markup but it's equally possible to just rely on the buttons above the text area.

Especially when you're asking a question, the editor has detailed formatting tips.

[image]

So in my opinion one does not have to know about using markup before posting on Stack Overflow, it is sufficient if one is willing to accept the help which is offered.

Comment: The same editor is on every site in the network, even sites with absolutely no relation to programming. And almost all of these people, even the non programmers, manage just fine. Thus I conclude that the editor is pretty easy to use.

Comment: @Laurel Have see quite a few questions on the review queues where the questions had to be edited. So for new users the editor takes time to get used to as well. I guess the fact that non-programmers using the editor does indicate its effectiveness. However can you get back if those users themselves are not programmers themselves? For example, does SE for english have more (unique) users than SO ?